# dynamically create a new ngmodel for binding in ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to create a dynamic object within an object in angular but I'm not sure of how to do it.

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat='role in roles' >
      <td>{{role.name}}</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        Total<input data-ng-model="mgmtData[roles[$index].code].total" type='number' min="0"/>
        <br>
        {{mgmtData.GM.total}}
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

and here is the controller snippet:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) { 

  $scope.mgmtData = {};

  $scope.roles = [
    {
      name: "General Manager",
      code: "GM"
    },
    {
      name: "Transport Manager",
      code: "TM"
    },
    {
      name: "Safety Executive",
      code: "SE"
    }
  ];

});
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>General Manager</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        Total<input data-ng-model="mgmtData.GM.total" type='number' min="0"/>
        <br>
        {{mgmtData.GM.total}}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transport Manager</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        Total<input data-ng-model="mgmtData.TM.total" type='number' min="0"/>
        <br>
        {{mgmtData.TM.total}}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Safety Executive</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        Total<input data-ng-model="mgmtData.SE.total" type='number' min="0"/>
        <br>
        {{mgmtData.SE.total}}
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What is the proper way to do this? I keep getting that is is unable to set property total of undefined. I'm assuming that it is because mgmtData is currently empty. However, I have no clue as to how to solve it

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your view should not be this complex when binding on data. The data should come from the controller. So it's better to put some $watch on your scope rather (If your scope.roles changes over time).

Answer (score 0):

Your `mgmtData` object is empty. Given the question, you would want to structure your object like this.

```
$scope.mgmtData = {
                   TM: {total: 'value'},
                   TM: {total: 'value'},
                   SE: {total: 'value'}
                  };
```

Only then you can access properties.

Idea here is that ng-model can create properties inside scope object for you automatically but it won't create object inside scope object for you.

Comment: Thanks hasH, I didn't know that AngularJS wasn't able to create an object inside.

Answer (score 0):

As what hasH mentioned, your `$scope.mgmtData` is not initialized, an alternative solution to this would be to use `ng-init` to initialize it during the iteration process. This method may provide useful whenever your $scope.roles array changes. e.g. requesting new roles from the server

**Add this to your controller**

```
$scope.initMgmtData = function(index) {
  $scope.mgmtData[$scope.roles[index].code] = {
    total: 0
  }
}
```

Add $scope.initMgmtData to `ng-init` directive, ideally before you use the `ng-model` directive within the `ng-repeat` scope.

```
<input ng-init="initMgmtData($index)" data-ng-model="mgmtData[role.code].total" type="number" min="0" />
```

[Associated PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/1zuZsA7LxK9LcCBIISF7?p=preview)